# Line break in JavaScript not appearing

Tags: javascript, line-breaks

I know there are other questions on this site, but I can't get their suggestions to work for me.

I have some JavaScript:

```
displayString = 'Text to go on line 1'+'<br/>'+'Text to go on line 2';
```

This appears on my webpage as it should, except there is no line break, and it just appears as:

```
"Text to go on line 1<br/>Text to go on line 2"
```

I have tried '/n' too, but that seems to just be omitted.

---

**Actual JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selectDirect').change(function(){
        if ($(this).val() === "450 Litre"){
            displayString = '450 Litre Vessel'+'<br/>'+'Combination Valve';
        }
        else if ($(this).val() === "550 Litre"){
            displayString = '550 Litre Vessel'+'<br/>'+'Combination Valve';
        }
        $("#choiceDisplay").text(displayString);
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you want HTML tags to be processed, you have to use `.html()`, not `.text()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) instead:

```
$("#choiceDisplay").html(displayString);
```

This will not escape html tags and in this case the `<br/>` tag.

Comment: `innerHTML` is a DOM attribute, not a jQuery method.

Comment: My bad. Use `html` instead.